# Deselect and toggle a radio button in angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons grouped as follows. And I want to select and deselect each radio button. And only one radio button should be active at once.

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='lightgreen'" [(ngModel)]="color">Green
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='yellow'" [(ngModel)]="color">Yellow
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='cyan'" [(ngModel)]="color">Cyan
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-color',
  templateUrl: './color.component.html'
})
export class ColorComponent {
  color: string;
  .........
}
```

The above code doesn't work. If I use `[(ngModel)]="color"` in one `<input type="radio" ...>` I can toggle that radio button. But selecting that radio button is interpreted as deselected and deselected as selected. Having `[(ngModel)]="color"` in all three breaks the code entirely.

Can someone please explain how to get this done ?

**EDIT:**

Found a way to deselect the radio buttons by introducing a button. But toggle doesn't work.

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="color" name="colors" value="lightgreen"/>Green
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="color" name="colors" value="yellow"/>Yellow
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="color" name="colors" value="cyan"/>Cyan
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="color=''">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Search for "angular forms radio buttoons" -> 2nd link :)

Taken from angular docs: [Using radio buttons with reactive form directives](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor#using-radio-buttons-with-reactive-form-directives)

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="beef" > Beef
      <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="lamb"> Lamb
      <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="fish"> Fish
    </form>

    <p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>  <!-- {food: 'lamb' } -->
  `,
})
export class ReactiveRadioButtonComp {
  form = new FormGroup({
    food: new FormControl('lamb'),
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to help. I still can't toggle the radio buttons